# Who owned the pit prison in Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises, dc

In the movie Dark Knight Rises Bruce Wayne is kept in prison which is in a pit. Earlier, this one in a kind prison was owed by a Warlord. But later in the story, although no official statement regarding the owner has been made, the unprecedented authority on the prison of Bane clearly makes him look like the owner. So, did Bane own the Prison? Or can anyone who has knowledge regarding the prison keep their prisoners there?

Comment: The RIAA. In the background you can see many people who torrented other Warner Bros. movies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it is never outright stated, an educated guess is that it is owned/controlled by the League of Shadows.  With

> Miranda Tate AKA Talia Al Ghul`

in charge and taking revenge on all those who wronged her and her family it stands to reason that she by way of Bane took control of the prison once she amassed enough power in the League.

Comment: If she owns it what is the purpose of keeping prisoners? She and Bane would have easily killed anyone...

Comment: You have to remember that the League doesn't believe that what they are doing is evil.  They don't kill without cause, so a prison to house their enemies they deem unnecessary to kill would make sense.  Plus it's a form of torture for those trapped there.

Comment: That settles it. Thanks!